# I am unable to load an image in my views using code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am new to codeigniter and i am trying to display a cover pic in the view welcome_message.php, but it doesn't seem to appear on my browser and i dont know why.
my controler looks like this

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');

}
}
```

please someone help me. the portion of my view that needs to load the image is

```
<img src="images/images1.jpeg" width="600" height="260"  />
```

the images are in a folder called images in the same directory

Comment: and what does you view `welcome_message` looks like?

Comment: post the welcome_message view

Comment: make sure images are in place and path is right

Answer (score 0):

You can use base_url function to get absolute url of image

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('images/images1.jpeg') ?>" width="600" height="260"  />
```

it should work if you have your image in root dir with `application` and `system` folders on same level.

**Note :** I dont think name of image is `images1.jpeg` it should `images1.jpg`

**Edit :** If you are using htaccess make sure its includes images folder like below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i tried that too but does not seem to work